# What happened to the community events that were announced?

Tags: discussion

I looked earlier and there was some really great posts from Rich about the Community Newsletter and advertising community events, and all this really cool community engagement.

I even see Akshay get into the mood and post a few events. Then I come back a few hours later and everything is gone.

Answer (score 1):

This has now been resolved.

The TL;DR of it is; we do not want to use this feature as a facility to advertise just anything - it has to be pure community events. I think we all have a pretty good idea of what those are (User Groups, SUGCON, Hackathon) - events organised by and for the community with no commercial interests as an underlying theme.

We'll make sure tag descriptions and wikis make this clear, and provide clear instructions on how to feed back to us with any new event types that should be considered valid for posting on the Community Bulletin.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Events are great and everyone agrees we should use them; we just need to decide exactly how we'll be using them.

There will be a further discussion between us and the Stack Exchange staff to determine how to handle such events, and where to draw the line between community events and third-party events. For the time being, this is on hold, which is why we'll refrain from using the Events feature for a while.

Comment: Yeah, it'll be interesting to see where this nets out.